# AngularJS - dynamic forms can't access FormController

Tags: angularjs, forms

One customer can have multiple contact information. In order to model a user friendly html-form, I use a structure similar to this one:

```
<div>
    <customer-form/>     <!-- single <form> element containing general customer information like name and address -->
    <contact-form        <!-- multiple <form> elements containing contact data-->
        ng-repeat="data in model track by $rowNumber"
        model="data" />
</div>
```

The graphical output of the contact form:

[image: Graphical output]

How it works:

- When the user enters data in the last row, `$scope.model.push({});` is triggered which automatically adds a new row
- When the <kbd>X</kbd> button is clicked, the current row is deleted with `$scope.model.splice(rowNumber, 1);`

When the user clicks <kbd>save</kbd>, I validate the forms and then check if there are any validation problems. If not, I check if the form contains data and send the filtered model to the server.

This is the validation part inside each contact form:

```
$scope.isValid = function (index){
    return !$scope.contactForm.$invalid;
};
```

The problem here is, that `$scope.contactForm` is sometimes `undefined`.
When I delete row number 1, all forms afterwards (1, 2, 3...) can't access their `contactForm` anymore although the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form) states

> If the name attribute is specified, the form controller is published
>   onto the current scope under this name.

-- which I did. Another problem is that the model is also cleared for those form-rows (I think they are initialised again). The html output works fine, but `$scope.model[...]` is empty - and they are not sent to the server.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any workaround for this or another possibility to deal with dynamic forms?

Answer (score 0):

As a **workaround** for this issue I am currently using this approach:

To delete a form, I "mark" it as not available:

```
function deleteForm(rowNumber){
    $scope.model[rowNumber] = null;
}
```

The following function checks if the given row should be treated as deleted or not:

```
function isAvailable(rowNumber){            
    return $scope.model[rowNumber] != null;
}
```

To hide the form from the user, I use `ng-if`:

```
<contact-form
    ng-repeat="data in model track by $rowNumber"
    ng-if="isAvailable($rowNumber)"
    model="data" />
```

And every function (`isValid()`, `containsData()`, ...) checks if the row should exist and ignores the form if not.

However, this workaround doesn't support reordering.